# Gitweb gives 404 no projects found

Tags: apache-2.2, git, gitolite

I'm having trouble setting up gitweb with gitolite. Gitolite works correctly, but gitweb keeps giving me a 404 - no projects found.

What's strange is that when I run the cgi script as the apache user the following way it seems to work correctly.

```
# su apache /var/www/git/gitweb.cgi --shell=/bin/sh
....
<tr class="dark">
<td><a class="list" href="?p=testing.git;a=summary">testing.git</a></td>
<td><a class="list" title="Test repo 3" href="?p=testing.git;a=summary">Test repo 3</a></td>
...
```

Gitweb should have reading access, and I've set `$REPO_UMASK = 0022;` in gitweb.conf and added apache to the gitolite group `# usermod -a -G gitolite apache`

```
# ls -l gitolite/
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 gitolite gitolite   12 Sep 28 08:47 projects.list
drwxr-x---. 4 gitolite gitolite 4096 Sep 28 04:52 repositories
```

My apache git config:

```
Alias /git /var/www/git

<Directory /var/www/git>
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
</Directory>
```

Can anyone help me get this working? Been trying all day, reading different blogs and posts but it just won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it! I am running on RHEL and it turns out it was a problem with SELinux. When I disabled it, everything worked correctly. Since I didn't want to disable it for good, I found the [solution on a blog](http://blog.spkane.org/2011/08/getting-gitweb-to-work-with-gitolite.html) for writing a module that sets the correct policies and installs it.

What I did was:

```
# mkdir gitolite-selinux; cd gitolite-selinux
# touch local.te local.if local.fc
# vim local.te

module gitolite 1.0;

require {
type git_system_t;
type httpd_t;
type var_t;
type gitosis_var_lib_t;
type httpd_git_script_t;
class dir { search read getattr open };
class file { getattr read open ioctl };
}

#============= git_system_t ==============
allow git_system_t gitosis_var_lib_t:dir { read search open getattr };
allow git_system_t gitosis_var_lib_t:file { read getattr open };

#============= httpd_git_script_t ==============
allow httpd_git_script_t gitosis_var_lib_t:dir { read search open getattr };
allow httpd_git_script_t gitosis_var_lib_t:file { read getattr open ioctl };

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t var_t:file getattr;

# make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile
# semodule -i gitolite.pp
```